# Elasticsearch - Making a field aggregatable but not searchable

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch data has a large number of fields that I don't need to search by. But I would like to get aggregations like percentiles, median, count, avg. etc. on these fields.

Is there a way to disable searchability of a field but let it still be aggregatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the fields are indexed by default and hence make them searchable. If you want to make a field non-searchable all you have to do is set its `index` param as `false` and `doc_values` to `true`.
As per elastic documentation:

> All fields which support doc values have them enabled by default.

So you need not explicitly set `"doc_values": true` for such fields.

For e.g.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "only_agg": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you try to search on field `only_agg` in above example, elastic will throw exception with reason as below:

```
Cannot search on field [only_agg] since it is not indexed.
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah take a look at doc_value:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html